# What is the best way to shred celery?

Tags: celery

Shredded celery is a tasty replacement for high-carb staples such as potatoes, pasta, and rice, and it has fewer calories than other foods that that is also true of, such as spaghettified courgette and celeriac.

But it doesn't shred well in a spiraliser, not being as hard as celeriac or as well-behaved as courgette. And a grater will turn it almost to pulp. The best way I have found so far is to use a julienne mill, but that tends to shred not hugely more than half of the celery I put in, leaving the rest in large soggy lumps.

I would like to make "celeretti" with long strands similar to "courgetti". But I would like to do it with celery sticks, not with celeriac. Whereas celeriac has about two and half times more calories per 100g than courgette, celery has about the same amount.

Suggestions?

Comment: Like this ? :  :-)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QqVxmsRctg

Comment: That's a nice video, but how the celery come out the other side? I think that's a waste disposal unit.

Comment: @ruffle I think that's the point. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a mandoline with the julienne attachment and cut them lenghtwise.

Or try do it manually with your knife.

Personally, I think that celery is a hard vegetable to make into spaghetti.

Comment: Lengthwise won't you wind up with very stringy "spaghetti"? (but i guess that is the meaning of the word):  +1 for your last sentence

Comment: Possibly, but the stringiness of celery is not something that's ever bothered me, although I know it bothers some people.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a mandoline, I'd use a vegetable peeler ... but I'd first try to remove the outer 'back' fibers, as they tend to be the toughest.  (you can often just start peeling the back (outer / convex) side and then pull to get those out).

And then I'd use a vegetable peeler but work from side to side rather than back to front, so I had more uniformly wide strips.

Comment: If you aren't going for strips ... then a mandoline or similar, but I'd personally hold the stalk at an angle rather than perpendicular (ie, bias cut), so you got larger slices